# How can I optimise this?

Tags: python, optimization

I wrote a little algorithm that uses the Trapezium Rule to find an estimation for area under the curve between two points, but it doesn’t run the absolute fastest, how can I optimise it? It’s in python (I know python is a slow language but I just want python optimisations).

```
start = -2
end = 0
num = 1000
eq = lambda x: x*(x**2 -4)

h = (end - start)/num
a = start - h 
ran = []
while a < end: 
  a += h 
  ran.append(round(a, 5))
values = [abs(eq(i)) for i in ran]
final = 0.5 * h * (values[0] + values[-1] + 2*sum(values[1:-1]))

print(final)
```

Comment: If you can, use numpy

Comment: Why the `round` call?

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, it's over 60 times faster on my machine:

```
start = -2
end = 0
num = 1000
eq = lambda x: x*(x**2 -4)

h = (end - start)/num
ran = np.arange(start - h, end, h)
values = eq(ran)
return 0.5 * h * (values[0] + values[-1] + 2*np.sum(values[1:-1]))
```

There's no reason to do it "manually" like this though – [`numpy.trapz`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) has you covered.